# php page inserting blank field

Tags: php, sql

My PHP page inserts blank fields into my database. I am using multiple forms to get my information and the database is still receiving and displaying blank data. Please can some one help.

My code for the PHP is:

```
<div id="User_username_input">

    <div id="User_username_inputleft"></div>

    <div id="User_username_inputmiddle">
    <form action='VerifyLogin.php' method='post'>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="url" value="User Name" onclick="this.value = ''">
        <img id="User_url_user" src="./images/mailicon.png" alt="">
    </form>
    </div>

    <div id="User_username_inputright"></div>

</div>


<div id="submit">
    <form action='VerifyLogin.php' method='post'>
    <input type="image" src="./images/submit_hover.png" id="submit1" value="fign In">
    <input type="image" src="./images/submit.png" id="submit2" value="Sign In">
    </form>
</div>
```

The page that post this data to the database is shown below:

```
<?php

include("verifyconect.php");

$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$confirm_password = $_POST['confirm_password'];

$insert = 'INSERT INTO verify (username, email, password, confirm_password) VALUES ("'.$username.'", "'.$email.'", "'.$password.'", "'.$confirm_password.'")';

mysql_query($insert);

echo "You have verified your details, Thank you";

?>
```

`verifyconnect.php` links the information to the database, so the code for it is not important. Please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You've posted your HTML twice rather than the PHP.

Comment: Even if it's not the `onclick="this.value = ''"` part that's causing it, it would be much better to use the [`placeholder`](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder) attribute instead.

Comment: You should rewrite this completely. Now you have an sql injection problem, you are using deprecated database functions and you are storing a plain-text password.

Comment: except username you dont have any other values in form

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: By the way, you're using two forms using the same action; which one is it?

Comment: You have SQL injection as the client can input anything they want to the database via. the $_POST['someVariable'] and you are using a deprecated mysql_* api. Search either and you will be awarded with code to refactor. After refactor you will feel much better and anyone looking at the code will not be distracted by it. The issue you are trying to solve is minor compared with the problems the security holes and use of deprecated mysql_* functions inforce.

Comment: @jeroen Not just storing the plain-text password once, but *twice* for good measure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most fundamental problem is you are using 2 forms when only one is needed. All elements must be placed in the single form for them to be sent via `POST` correctly. So change your HTML to this:

```
<div id="User_username_input">

    <div id="User_username_inputleft"></div>

    <div id="User_username_inputmiddle">
    <form action='VerifyLogin.php' method='post'>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="url" value="User Name" onclick="this.value = ''">
        <div id="submit">
          <input type="image" src="./images/submit_hover.png" id="submit1" value="fign In">
          <input type="image" src="./images/submit.png" id="submit2" value="Sign In">
        </div>
        <img id="User_url_user" src="./images/mailicon.png" alt="">
    </form>
    </div>

    <div id="User_username_inputright"></div>

</div>
```

The explanation using your code boils down to this. Removing your `DIV`’s for clarity.:

```
<form action='VerifyLogin.php' method='post'>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="url" value="User Name" onclick="this.value = ''">
</form>

<form action='VerifyLogin.php' method='post'>
  <input type="image" src="./images/submit_hover.png" id="submit1" value="fign In">
  <input type="image" src="./images/submit.png" id="submit2" value="Sign In">
</form>
```

Look at the two form areas. If you hit <kbd>submit</kbd> then it only parses the values in that second form which only has <kbd>submit</kbd> buttons.  The first form with the `username` lives in it’s own separate world that will never be summated since it has 100% no <kbd>submit</kbd> button.

But past that your code is a mess & needs a lot of refactoring. Also—and I bet I will not be the only one saying this—but you should replace all your calls using `mysql_*` extensions to `mysqli_*` extensions since not only is `mysql_*` depreciated as of PHP 5.3, but is completely gone in PHP 5.5. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: I have ammended the code, and made it a single form page. But the error remains please what else can i do to get it sorted. What do you mean by replace all my calls please?

Comment: Thanks @JakeGould, your suggestion works, i deleted the other submit and it works now..Many thanks.